# getCookies() In servlet always returning null

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, cookies

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I need to set a cookie that identifies the browser and send it to the server to do custom XSL formatting based on the browser.  In the JSP, I put in the following code (detectBrowser() is a JS function that determines the type of browser):

```
document.cookie="browser=" + detectBrowser();
```

I then submit the request to a servlet.  When I monitor the request with Fiddler, I can see that the cookie named "browser" is being sent to the server:

[image]

However, when I try to retrieve the cookie with this code:

```
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies(); 
        if (cookies != null && cookies.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                String name = cookies[i].getName();
                String value = cookies[i].getValue();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("browser")) {
                    session.setAttribute("browser", value);
                }
            }
        }
```

The array "cookies" is always null.  So I'm confused -- the Fiddler scan seems to confirm that the cookie is being sent from the browser to the server, and yet the servlet does not seem to be able to grab it?

Any ideas?  I am using TomEE with Tomcat 7 web server, and this behavior is consistent among all browsers -- the Fiddler scan says that it correctly sends the cookie along to the server but the servlet always gets a null when I execute the request.getCookies() function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What all attributes are there in your tomcat 7 conf/context.xml ? Have you checked if cookies are not disabled in it ?

Comment: context.xml is pretty much empty, except for the "useHttpOnly" argument set to "true" for JSESSIONID.  Is it possible to enable/disable cookies in Tomcat?

Comment: Yes I guess the cookie parameters are only for the JSessionID only. Can you please post whole your method from where you are trying to get the cookies ?